# Horizontal Table design using Gridview, Repeater etc

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

Im looking to build a nice form which a supplier can quote prices on. SO the form will have Labels down the left hand side and then their would be a Column per requested Product/Quantity from the buyer. So it would have n number of columns.

Because of the way html tables are coded you need to build a row at a time. (I want to keep this as one table so its neat HTML)

Before I go ahead and create Repeater for each row of information the user needs to enter. Is their a way to be able to create a sorta grid view but instead of each records you pass it going to create a new row. It would create a new column and you could define the first column as the header column?

My table sort design is (txtb stands for textbox and lbl stands for label which is updated as values are entered)

Quantity        500    1000    2000

Delivery Cost   txtb   txtb    txtb

Pricing         txtb   txtb    txtb

Total Cost      lbl    lbl     lbl

Exchange Rate   txtb   txtb    txtb

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest using `ul` tags (unordered lists). They suite your requirement much more easier, as I've done it in a similar situation. Table will cause you many pains down the way.

Comment: this is not a bad idea but doesn't keep the individual lists connected together in height etc. Like a Table would

Comment: No, believe me, creating what you need with CSS and li items is really easier than table. But on the condition that you know CSS well. :)

Comment: I'll take your advise and build it this way. Seeing as I do know CSS very well

Comment: In that case, vote up this answer, or check it as correct answer, so that others also can easily find it. :)

Comment: I Will once I've done the work and it provides to be a good success :)

Comment: It's come out looking pretty good once I had the LI heights and widths sorted, I could easily align the text to the textboxes

Answer (score 0):

Are these labels/controls fixed? Because if so you don't need to write a control to render them, you could just code the HTML straight in.

If you are generating the form from a data-source then there are a number of ways to do this in Web Forms, however for simplicity I would stick to a Repeater, it's the cleanest way to achieve this, particularly if you don't need the bells and whistles in the other controls.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptFields">
<HeaderTemplate>
   <table>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
   <tr>
      <td><%#Eval("Label") %></td>
      <td><asp:Textbox runat="server"/></td>
   </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>
```

However bear in mind if you generate these controls you will not be able to access them from he code-behind directly, you would have to access them through the form fields or the repeater.

Comment: I would like to stick to a repeater as its clean but this doesn't solve the problem as you Have a 2 column table in your example. with each Repeat creating a new ROW. Mine would need to create a New Column per Repeat!

Comment: That's easy, you can have nested repeaters, 1 for the rows and then 1 for the columns.

Comment: that wouldnt work. you cannot have nested for each row as each row is different (goes textbox, label, label textbox, label, textbox etc) I could have 14 repeaters to do each row but this would be extreme I think